# anaconda environment in VS-Code can't find anaconda libraries

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to run some python code with VS Code in an anaconda environment and I get an error: `ImportError: libpython3.7m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

my working directory in anaconda is `/home/usr`
I know for sure that `libPython3.7m.so.1.0` is in `/home/usr/anaconda3/lib` so I have tried:
`export PATH="/home/usr/anaconda3/lib:$PATH"` and `export PYTHONPATH="/home/usr/anaconda3/lib:$PATH"` but it still can't find the libraries.

What could I be doing wrong?